# IPC using pipes?

Tags: c++, unix, pipe, named-pipes

I m trying to implement a program using pipes where parent process accepts a string and passes it to child process. Need to be done with only single pipe. How does the pipe read & write accepts string.

Here is my sample code! all!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int pid[2];
  ssize_t fbytes;
  pid_t childpid;
  char str[20], rev[20];
  char buf[20], red[20];

  pipe(pid);

  if ((childpid = fork()) == -1) {
    perror("Fork");
    return(1);
  }

  if (childpid == 0) {
    // child process close the input side of the pipe
    close(pid[0]);

    int i = -1, j = 0;
    while (str[++i] != '\0') {
      while(i >= 0) {
        rev[j++] = str[--i];
      }
      rev[j] = '\0';
    }

    // Send reversed string through the output side of pipe
    write(pid[1], rev, sizeof(rev));
    close(pid[0]);
    return(0);
  } else {
    cout << "Enter a String: ";
    cin.getline(str, 20);

    // Parent process closing the output side of pipe.
    close(pid[1]);

    // reading the string from the pipe
    fbytes = read(pid[0], buf, sizeof(buf));
    cout << "Reversed string: " << buf;
    close(pid[0]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are the purposes of `rev`, `red`, `str`, and `buf`?  It looks like those obfuscated names are contributing to the problem.

Comment: Yes, all fine! And what's your question in particular please?

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never pass the string to be reversed to the child, so it reverses some random garbage and sends it to the parent.

Minor issues:

```
write(pid[1], rev, sizeof(rev));
close(pid[0]); // Should be pid[1]
return(0); // Should be _exit(0)
```

The reason you don't want to `return` from `main` in the child is that you don't know what consequences that will have. You may call exit handlers that manipulate real world objects that the parent expects to remain intact.

Comment: how to pass the string to child?

Comment: @user3767923 step through your code carefully.  You have one process immediately copying `str` while the other process eventually initializes it.

Comment: what do I need to do, will adding sleep() help?

Comment: @user3767923 It depends what you want to do. Maybe you want to create a second pipe for the other direction? Maybe you want to input the string before you call `fork`? Unfortunately, `sleep()` won't help. This isn't a race condition. You just forgot to pass the string to the child.

Comment: Is it possible with only one pipe?

Comment: It probably is because pipes on most platforms are bidirectional. But it's not guaranteed to work -- pipes can be unidirectional. Perhaps you should switch from a pipe to something guaranteed bidirectional. (UNIX domain stream socket?)